# mke2fs writes 2.4 GiB to disk

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, ext4, ssd

Using the Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit Desktop LiveCD, I created a 149.04 GiB partition using gdisk on an unpartitioned SSD. I opened gparted to notice that nothing has been written to the new partition. Then I used mke2fs like this:

```
sudo mke2fs -t ext4 -O ^has_journal /dev/sda1
```

Right after, I opened gparted to notice 2.40 GiB has been written to this partition. What has just been written? I thought

```
-O ^has_journal
```

makes sure a journal isn't created. So what was actually written to the partition?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that is the space used by http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#DEF-SUPERBLOCK .